# Determine the result of parallel translating the vector $(0, 0, 1)$ once around the circle $x^2+ y^2=a^2, z=0$

Tags: differential-geometry

can any one solve this problem

> **Q**)
>   Determine the result of parallel translating the vector $(0, 0, 1)$ once around the circle $x^2+ y^2=a^2, z=0$ .On the right circular cylinder $x^2 + y^2 =a^2$?

what happen if 
Determine the result of parallel translating the vector $(0, 0, 1)$ once around the circle $x^2+ y^2=a^2, z=0$ .On the right circular cone $x^2 + y^2 =a^2$?

I hope someone can solve this problem and answer also what is the parametrization of cone and cylinder in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: I already gave you parameterizations of cylinder and cone, in my answer to your other question(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some parts of the question are not very clear, so I'll just address the part that says: "determine the result of parallel translating the vector $(0,0,1)$  once around the circle $x^2 + y^ 2 = a^2$, $z=0$".

Since this is an elementary question, I expect "the vector $(0,0,1)$" actually means a line in the direction $(0,0,1)$. This is the thick blue line in the picture. Let's orient ourselves so that this line is vertical. Then the given circle lies in a horizonal plane. This circle is shown in red in the picture. If the blue line travels around the red circle, it will sweep out a cylindrical shape, shown shaded in pale blue. In fact, this cylinder will have the equation $x^2 + y^ 2 = a^2$. This is a right circular cylinder with radius $a$ (the same as the circle).

[image: cylinder]

I already answered your questions about parameterizations of cylinders and cones, but I'll repeat part of my answer here.

The cylinder we have been discussing has a parameterization:

$$P(u,v) = (a\cos u, a\sin u, v)$$

It is helpful to write this as

$$P(u,v) = (a\cos u, a\sin u, 0) + v(0,0,1)$$

Let's think about what this says. Given two parameter values $u$ and $v$, this equation tells us how to get to a point $P(u,v)$ on the cylinder. The picture below shows how this works.

[image: cylinder parameterization]

The equation says we should first go to the point $(a\cos u, a\sin u, 0)$, which at an angle $u$ on the red circle. This is the green point in the picture. Then we should travel vertically a distance $v$ along the vector $(0,0,1)$ (i.e. up one of the blue lines). This brings us to the pink point in the picture, which is $P(u,v)$.

From this, you should be able to see how the blue lines generate the cylinder.

Comment: i have question what happen if we change question replace cylinder to cone what the change happen please thanks

Comment: what happen if we have cone

Comment: In several places (in several different questions), you have asked about "the cone $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$. This is **not** a cone, it's cylinder. The equation $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ represents a cone. Note the $z^2$ on the right-hand side, not $a^2$.

Comment: Where are these questions coming from? Are you studying "parallel transport" in differential geometry, or are you just studying equations of simple geometric shapes (like cones and cylinders). If you're studying differential geometry, how much do you know? Do you know about Christoffel symbols, for example? What textbook are you using? People can give you better answers, if they understand how much you already know.

Answer (score 3):

The cylinder is a flat space (it is a curled up Euclidean plane) so the result is $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: sorry this incorrect answer

Comment: @leenaadam What should it be then?

Comment: @leenaadam incorrect answer described as “exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty” ????

Comment: please can any one solve this problem

Comment: I think the answer should be $ (0,0,1) $ as pointed out earlier, because the cylinder is locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2 $ that is of zero curvature, so Christoffel symbols vanish. $ V(t) = (V_1(t),V_2(t)) $ being the parallel translate along $\gamma $ which is the circle in this case, then covariant derivative $D_t(V) = 0 $ which means 
$$ V'_k(t) + \sum_{i,j}V_j(t)\gamma_i(t)\Gamma^k_{ij}(\gamma(t)) = 0 $$ which in this case reduces to $ V'_k(t) = 0 $. So the operator of parallel translation reduces to identity as in $\mathbb{R}^2 $

Comment: can you please explain more